# How do I make Ubuntu not require a password to supend?

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, password, xfce4-power-manager

I use Lubuntu 17.10. I have my desktop set to suspend after 5 minutes of inactivity, but every time I come back, I'm greeted with this error message:

```
Password required to suspend
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: I don't have 17.10, using 18.04 where this can be changed in gsettings or dconf-editor. To see if 17.10 is doing the same run this command. If it returns a valid value (in your case true) then it's easy to change. (- assuming your using gnome-shell, if using ubuntu the setting is in system settings > Brightness & Lock)  `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend`   If using gnome-shell & this command errors run this to see what keys are there `gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.screensaver`